# Show that length of longest edge in Delaunay triangulation goes to zero

Tags: general-topology, triangulation

Suppose that we have a set of vertices $V$ in a certain space $\Omega$ and that we iteratively add a vertex to $V$ and build a Delaunay triangulation on these vertices. Now, if $\mathcal{T}^1$, $\mathcal{T}^2$, ... denotes the corresponding sequence of Delaunay triangulations, I would like to show that the length of the longest edges in these triangulations, denoted by $|\mathcal{T}^j|$ goes to $0$ as $j \rightarrow \infty$.
I am wondering if this is even true and what conditions the space $\Omega$ needs to satisfy to obtain this result. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Let $V$ have three points in the plane. Add vertices only in the interior of the triangle. Then the longest Delaunay edge is one of the sides of the triangle, and so does not shrink to a point.

Comment: And what if you also add vertices to the boundary?